# UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES in Django

Tags: django

in Django,
almost all the variables' naming style is UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES,
for instance:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [

]
```

and so on...

what's the conventions it follows?

Comment: These are treated as constants https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pep8, its common across most python and PyCharm helps to enforce it.

In particular, this is [the rule for constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to being constants and following PEP8, these constants are *Django settings*. Settings are defined in a settings module, and Django exposes an object, `django.conf.settings`, that proxies attributes in this module. The proxy object only exposes settings that are all uppercase.

So if you want your settings to be available on `django.conf.settings`, using uppercase variable names is not just a convention, it's required.

Comment: I just ran into this, because I copied a variable name into my settings.py, and it wasn't uppercased. A warning would've been nice...

Answer (score 1):

It follows [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

The letters are upper case because they are constants. And the underscore is a usual python naming convention.

```
UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
```

Answer (score 0):

Django setting required uppercase letter for custom-defined settings variables
These are certain rules in Django for creating our own settings
Creating your own settings
There’s nothing stopping you from creating your own settings, for your own Django apps, but follow these guidelines:
Setting names must be all uppercase.
Don’t reinvent an already-existing setting.
For settings that are sequences, Django itself uses lists, but this is only a convention.
Please have a look at Django documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

Django itself follows that rules and Naming convention in python like splits with the underscores are from pep8.